# Is there any way to speed up the computation time of calling a function with multiple time in python?

Tags: python, performance, review

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from numpy import random
    import time
    from collections import Counter
   
    def simulation(N):
        I = 10
        success = 0
        M = 100
        for i in range(I):
            s = allocate(N,M)
            M -= s
            success += s
        return success

    def allocate(N,M):
        count = Counter(random.randint(N,size = M))
        success = sum(j for v,j in count.items() if j == 1)
        return success

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        start = time.perf_counter() 
        SAMPLE_SIZE = 100000
        N = np.linspace(5,45,41).astype(int)
        Ps = []
        for n in N:
            ps = []
            for _ in range(SAMPLE_SIZE):
                ps.append(simulation(n)/100)
            result = np.average(np.array(ps))
            Ps.append(result)

        elapsed = (time.perf_counter() - start)
        print("Time used:",elapsed)
        plt.scatter(N,Ps)
        plt.show()
```

Here is my situation. The ultimate goal is to set SAMPLE_SIZE to 10^7. However, when I set it to 10^5, it already requires about 1000sec to run it. Is there any way to make it more efficient and faster? Thanks for giving me suggestions.

Comment: You should probably look into threading and/or multiprocessing.

Comment: Please provide full runnable code (you are missing imports).

Comment: @TYZ Thank you i will check it

Comment: @mikulatomas   I just edit and add the import part. Thank you.

Comment: Plain CPython multithreading will not be useful. You should go with numba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the implementation of `allocate` is not very efficient: you can **use vectorized Numpy function** to do that:

```py
def allocate(N, M):
    success = np.count_nonzero(np.bincount(random.randint(N, size=M)) == 1)
    return success
```

The thing is most of the time comes from the overhead of Numpy functions performing some checks and create some temporary arrays. You can **use Numba** to fix this problem:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('int_(int_, int_)')
def allocate(N,M):
    tmp = np.zeros(N, np.int_)
    for i in range(M):
        rnd = np.random.randint(0, N)
        tmp[rnd] += 1
    count = 0
    for i in range(N):
        count += tmp[i] == 1
    return count
```

Then, you can speed up the code a bit further by using the Numba decorator `@nb.njit('int_(int_)')` to the `simulation` function so to avoid the overhead of calling Numba functions from the CPython interpreter.

Finally, you can speed up the main loop by running it in **parallel** with Numba (and also avoid the use of *slow lists*). You can also recycle the `tmp` array so not to cause too many allocations (that are expensive and do not scale with the number of cores). Here is the resulting final code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numba as nb

# Recycle the `tmp` buffer not to do many allocations
@nb.njit('int_(int_, int_, int_[::1])')
def allocate(N, M, tmp):
    tmp.fill(0)
    for i in range(M):
        rnd = np.random.randint(0, N)
        tmp[rnd] += 1
    count = 0
    for i in range(N):
        count += tmp[i] == 1
    return count

@nb.njit('int_(int_)')
def simulation(N):
    I = 10
    success = 0
    M = 100
    tmp = np.zeros(N, np.int_) # Preallocated buffer
    for i in range(I):
        s = allocate(N, M, tmp)
        M -= s
        success += s
    return success

@nb.njit('float64(int_, int_)', parallel=True)
def compute_ps_avg(n, sample_size):
    ps = np.zeros(sample_size, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in nb.prange(sample_size):
        ps[i] = simulation(n) / 100.0
    # Note that np.average is not yet supported by Numba
    return np.mean(ps)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter() 
    SAMPLE_SIZE = 100_000
    N = np.linspace(5,45,41).astype(int)
    Ps = [compute_ps_avg(n, SAMPLE_SIZE) for n in N]
    elapsed = (time.perf_counter() - start)
    print("Time used:",elapsed)
    plt.scatter(N,Ps)
    plt.show()
```

Here are performance results on my 10-core machine:

```
Initial code:          670.6 s
Optimized Numba code:    3.9 s
```

The resulting code is **172 times faster**.

More than 80% of the time is spent in the generation of random numbers. Thus, if you want the code to be faster, one solution is to speed up the generation of random number using a SIMD-optimized random number generator. Unfortunately, AFAIK, this is not possible to (efficiently) achieve this in Python. You certainly need to use a native language like C or C++ to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and useful explanation. Really appreciate for it!

Comment: @MauYin Do not forget to validate the answer if it solved your problem ;) .

Comment: Sorry it's my first time asking a question here. To validate the answer, am I just need to click the 'tick' button? Thank you very much.

Comment: OMP: Info #271: omp_set_nested routine deprecated, please use omp_set_max_active_levels instead. Sorry for asking you again. I just test the code and it run well. However, there is an error in the terminal. But still, I can get the output correctly, may I ask is it a big problem?

Comment: This error is quite weird. It should not appear. This may be because a parallel code is running in another parallel OpenMP section (OpenMP is the threading backend used by Numba here). If so, this is generally pretty bad for performance. It should not be possible here since there is only one parallel section. You can check the number of actively running threads. If it is not much more than the number of hardware thread (or core) of your processor, then it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the point but it seems like you can replace your simulation with a closed form calculation.

I believe the problem you are solving is find the expected number of boxes with exactly 1 ball in them given a random distribution of M balls in N boxes.

Follow the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66094 to get the closed form expression (André Nicolas solved it for 10 balls and 5 boxes but you should be able to extrapolate)

(As a side note I will often also write code to confirm that my probability calculations are correct, if this is what you are doing sorry about stating the obvious :P )

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try implementing it into my program. Hope it can become more effiicient.