# Is there any possible way to make this code more efficient and faster?

Tags: python, numba, coding-efficiency

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from numba import njit, prange

@njit('int_(int_, int_, int_[::1])')
def aloha(N, M, tmp):
    tmp.fill(0)
    for i in range(M):
        rnd = np.random.randint(0, N)
        tmp[rnd] += 1
    success = 0
    for i in range(N):
        success += tmp[i] == 1
    return success

@njit('float64(int_, int_, int_[::1])')
def repetition(I,M,tmp):
    s = 0
    for i in range(I):
        s += aloha(12, M, tmp)
    return s/I
    
@njit('float64[::1](int_)')
def simulation(M):
    tmp = np.zeros(12, np.int_) # Preallocated buffer
    success_0 = 0
    success_1 = 0
    success_2 = 0
    M0 = M
    M1 = M
    M2 = M
    s = 0
    # 1-5
    for j in range(5):
        s = 0
        # CE Lv 0
        s = repetition(8,round(M0),tmp)
        M0 -= s
        success_0 += s
        # CE Lv 1
        s = repetition(32,round(M1),tmp)
        M1 -= s
        success_1 += s
        # CE Lv 2
        s = repetition(128,round(M2),tmp)
        M2 -= s
        success_2 += s
    # 6-10
    for j in range(5):
        s = 0
        # CE Lv 0
        s = repetition(32,round(M0),tmp)
        M0 -= s
        success_0 += s
         # CE Lv 1 and 2
        M1 = M1 + M2
        s = repetition(128,round(M1),tmp)
        M1 -= s
        success_1 += s
        success_2 += s
    # 11-15
    for j in range(5):
        s = 0
        # CE Lv 0
        M0 = M0 + M1
        s = repetition(128,int(M0),tmp)
        M0 -= s
        success_0 += s
        success_1 += s
        success_2 += s
    return np.array([success_0/M,success_1/M,success_2/M], dtype=np.float64)

@njit('float64[::1](int_, int_)', parallel=True)
def compute_ps_avg(m, sample_size):
    s0 = np.zeros(sample_size, dtype=np.float64)
    s1 = np.zeros(sample_size, dtype=np.float64)
    s2 = np.zeros(sample_size, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in prange(sample_size):
        arr = simulation(m)
        s0[i]= arr[0]
        s1[i] = arr[2]
        s2[i] = arr[1]
    s0_result = np.mean(s0)
    s1_result = np.mean(s1)
    s2_result = np.mean(s2)
    return np.array([s0_result,s1_result,s2_result])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter() 
    SAMPLE_SIZE = 100
    M = np.linspace(10,100,10)
    Result = [compute_ps_avg(m, SAMPLE_SIZE) for m in M]
    print(Result)
    Flatted = np.reshape(Result,-1)
    s0 = Flatted[0::3]
    s1 = Flatted[1::3]
    s2 = Flatted[2::3]
    elapsed = (time.perf_counter() - start)
    print("Time used:",elapsed)
    plt.scatter(M,s0,marker='s', facecolors='none', edgecolors='b')
    plt.scatter(M,s1,marker='o')
    plt.scatter(M,s2,s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
    plt.ylim(ymin=0)
    plt.ylim(ymax=1.1)
    plt.xticks(M)
    plt.show()
```

The Ultimate goal is to run this program with SAMPLE_SIZE = 10^7 and run it with around 1000s. I already search on the internet and use numba to speed up a little bit but it doesn't enough. Is there any way to make it more efficient and faster? Thanks for giving me suggestions. It will help me a lot thank you so much.

Comment: The code is fine overall. it can probably be micro-optimized a bit, but as said in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899225/12939557) "*more than 80% of the time is spent in the generation of random numbers*" and you want to call `np.random.randint` 228_000_000_000 times... Numba is great but Python is clearly not the right tool to push the limit of the hardware. Thus, as I previously said, you need to use a native language so the execution can be much faster. Alternatively you need to rework the approach as they may be a better mathematical approach to this problem.

Comment: If you use a native language like C or C++, then note that SIMD instruction sets like AVX-2 on x86 processors can be used to generate 32 random integers at once in few cycles. AVX-512 available on few recent processors can even reach 64 random integers at once. This means at least an order of magnitude faster execution. GPU may help too but this is far more difficult to use them efficiently.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you again for answering me. Since I'm not familiar with C or C++ and there is not enough time for me to learn it from the beginning because I have to finish the project recently. So maybe I just keep the code and lower the sample size in order to achieve the goal. So thanks for your detailed answer again.